# Android developer tools show an empty window after open,it damaged?

Tags: android, eclipse

I download last android developer tools (Eclipse) from :

http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

But after a work time , it show me same window :

[image]

And it never close wile kill it in monitor.

My OS is Ubuntu.

Can anyone help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved !

I rename eclipse workspace for (you can delete if not have any projects).

Eclipse creates new workspace.

And it load fine.